# Which code segment performs well (Handling memory while assigning variables)+ java

Tags: java, android, memory-management

Code sample 1: Below code segment handles large size bitmaps ..

```
 //  Here reusing same variable "bitmap"  

    // Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap 
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoDir.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);

    //Re-sizing 
    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    bitmap =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, targetW, targetH,true);
    mtx.postRotate(90);

    // Rotating Bitmap
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, targetW, targetH, mtx, true);
    imgPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap );
```

Code Sample 2:

```
     //Here i used different variables

    // Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap 
    Bitmap orginalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoDir.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);

    //Re-sizing 
    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    Bitmap resizedBitmap =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(orginalBitmap , targetW, targetH,true);
    mtx.postRotate(90);

    // Rotating Bitmap
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(resizedBitmap , 0, 0, targetW, targetH, mtx, true);

    imgPhoto.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
```

Question : Which code segment is better in terms of memory and speed etc?

Comment: trace it, you'll see the memory used. I would go with 1 pointer only.

Comment: also, did you considered using bitmap.recycle ?

Comment: I also recommend http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html
You can compare both methods and you will see difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *principle*, it shouldn't make any difference. A good JVM will make an object garbage-collectable if the only reference is a local reference that is no longer actually going to be used so that your two code samples are to all intents and purposes identical.

I wonder if you're trying to invent a theoretical problem that doesn't exist? If you are actually running into a performance issue in practice, then profile. If not, don't worry too much.

Answer (score 1):

I think these should all be the same, right? I mean variables live on the stack, it's the heap impact here which will be noticeable. The size of 3 variables in this case is very negligible, like let's say in purest form 32 bit pointer + another 32 bits for meta data. 3 `long`s vs 1 `long`, you couldn't tell the difference on most modern machines (even the lowest spec android phone should not see a noticeable impact).

If you want a more efficient use of memory, the biggest gain from all of these I think would be if in the second with the 3 separate variables, you may be able to recycle the old bitmaps and only keep the one that is set on the image view. This will be a more efficient use of memory. Bitmaps are expensive because of the `byte[]` aspect. These aren't random allocs, these are contiguous blocks of memory which become very scarse as you allocate more `byte[]`'s of different sizes. So recycling will help a lot there.